# SQL Server mirroring connection issue

Tags: sql-server, database, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2012, database-mirroring

- Server A : Win 2008, SQL Server 2012, IP : 1.1.1.1 (Principal)
- Server B : Win 2008, SQL Server 2012, IP : 2.2.2.2 (Mirror)

2 servers are not on the same LAN, no domains, so I need to use IP for mirror configuration.

I followed the step by step article I found on internet and successfully setup the mirror.

However, first, when I open mirroring monitor on principal DB

[image]

There is error says not connected, it's understandable because 2 servers are in 2 different location, they can't recognize server name of each other.

I then try to edit the connection but no able to edit..

[image]

How should I fix here??

Second, I manually stop the principal server, for testing how to let mirror server take over..

```
alter database MirrorTest 
set partner force_service_allow_data_loss
```

it's no problem here, mirrored database shows "Principal, Disconnected" and works as normal

And then, when I try to resume mirroring...

[image]

Again, the connection show server name and not allow me to edit, and of course I can't connect back to original principal server

[image]

Therefore, I can't resume the mirroring..

Many thanks for any clue to fix the issue...

Comment: Mirroring setup is a bit tricky. I would recommend setting it up using SQL. If you are not using Active Directory you should use [certificates](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191140%28v=sql.110%29.aspx). In your case you have failed over without active fail over partner. Best solution is to start it over. Guide that worked for us is [here](https://translate.google.ru/translate?hl=en&sl=ru&u=http://andriy.co/Zerkalirovanie_bazy_dannyh_na_MSSQL_Server_2005_2008.aspx&prev=search)

Comment: This really doesn't have anything to do with **programming**, but with DB administration - so it's off-topic here and belongs on [dba.stackexchange.com](http://dba.stackexchange.com) - voting to move.

Comment: Figured out by override connection string, and I am sorry if I post this question in wrong forum...